# Strange hidden files suddenly appeared on my desktop

Tags: windows-10

My laptop runs Windows 10 x64 (ver 1511). Today, after clicking Quick Access from Windows Explorer, I found strange files that seem to be located in Desktop:

[image]

However, when I went to Desktop, these files weren't there, even after I chose to show hidden files and hidden system files. A full check from the most recently updated MalwareBytes returned no infection, neither did a full check from McAfee.

What do I do now please?

Comment: When was the date modified? Check to see if you have installed any new software. It could simply be caches.

Comment: have you googled any of the filenames?

Comment: Is everything else in English and these are the only characters that are not?

Comment: Yes everything else in English and these are the only characters that are not

Comment: I tried googling the names, but to no avail

Comment: There is no listing of data modified..moreover, the file sizes are 0 bytes each and they cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/17572-file-explorer-chinese-files-names-phantom-files.html), it is a corrupted profile. The solution is to create a new account or fix the [corrupted user profile](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7). The fix was for Windows 7 but the people on the forum from the first link were using Windows 10 and it worked for them.

Before you try that though, it could just be that Windows was unable to load the profile correctly. Try restarting and see it if still occurs.

> Occasionally, Windows might not read your user profile correctly—for example, if your antivirus software is scanning your computer while you try to log on. Before you create a new user profile, try restarting your computer and logging on with your user account again.